# Add another destination behind path read from registry

Tags: inno-setup

How is possible to add two subfolders behind a path read from registry?

```pascal
[Code]
function GetDirName(Value: string): string;
var          
  InstallPath: string;
begin
  Result := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\subfolder1\subfolder2';

  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\myapp', 'RootPath', InstallPath) then
    Result := InstallPath
  else
  // query the second registry value; if it succeeds, return the obtained value
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, '\SOFTWARE\myapp', 'RootPath', InstallPath) then
    Result := InstallPath;
end;
```

When I got the destination from register I need to add behind it `\subfolder1\subfolder2` and complete destination get to function `GetDirName`.

Can someone guide me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the two strings at the end of the `GetDirName` function:

```pascal
function GetDirName(Value: string): string;
var          
  InstallPath: string;
begin
  // expand path to the 32-bit Program Files folder with appended 'myapp' subfolder
  Result := ExpandConstant('{pf32}\myapp');

     // query value from 64-bit registry node (notice the used HKLM64 root key)
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\myapp', 'RootPath', InstallPath) or
     // query value from 32-bit registry node (notice the used HKLM32 root key)
     RegQueryStringValue(HKLM32, 'SOFTWARE\myapp', 'RootPath', InstallPath) then
  begin
    Result := InstallPath;
  end;

  // ensure the path will have backslash and append the final subdirectory string
  Result := AddBackslash(Result) + 'subfolder1\subfolder2';
end;
```